# How to show by the chain rule and the FTC?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

How can I apply the FTC and the chain rule to prove this:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y,z)dzdy=\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y,z)dz+\int_{a}^{x}\int_{c}^{d}f_{x}(x,y,z)dzdy.$$

Answer (score 1):

I forget about the inner integral because it does not play any role.

Define the function
$$
F(t,x)=\int_a^t f(x,y) \,d y\,.
$$
What you want to compute is nothing but
$$
\frac{d}{d x} (F\circ i)(x)
$$
where $i$ is the map $x\mapsto(x,x)$. By the chain rule, you have
$$
\frac{d}{d x} (F\circ i)(x)=(\nabla F)(i(x))\cdot \frac{d}{d x}i(x)=(\partial_t F)(x,x)+(\partial_x F)(x,x)
$$
because $\frac{d}{d x}i(x)=(1,1)$. To conclude, observe that
$$
(\partial_t F)(t,x)= f(x,t) \qquad (\partial_x F)(t,x)=\int_a^t (\partial_x f)(x,y) \,d y.
$$